# How to get the lock provider

Tags: magento2

Short and simple:

The "lock provider" can be set, this is nicely described here:

[Link to Magento Documentation about lock provider settings](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-lock.html)

How can one check which lock provider has been set? Can not find any get method.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

File - Magento2/vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/ConfigOptionsList/Lock.php

```
/**
     * Returns the name of lock provider
     *
     * @param array $options
     * @param DeploymentConfig $deploymentConfig
     * @return string
     */
    private function getLockProvider(array $options, DeploymentConfig $deploymentConfig): string
    {
        if (!isset($options[self::INPUT_KEY_LOCK_PROVIDER])) {
            return (string) $deploymentConfig->get(
                self::CONFIG_PATH_LOCK_PROVIDER,
                $this->getDefaultValue(self::INPUT_KEY_LOCK_PROVIDER)
            );
        }

        return (string) $options[self::INPUT_KEY_LOCK_PROVIDER];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `\Magento\Framework\Lock\LockManagerInterface`.

Docblocks should explain well enough how to use it.